# Mysql concat with regexp

Tags: mysql

please advise following sql:

I wish to replace text in a field where value similar "Priority: 1" with "Priority: 2".
However text to find could be "Priority: 1" OR "Priority: 2" OR "Priority: 3" etc.
Was thinking of using regexp along with concat to find any value that matches the pattern

An example of complete data in field:

```
 <span class='badge badge-info'>Priority: 1</span><br>&bull; Lead submitted: <br>&bull; Existing customer: <br>&bull; Car of interest:
```

In this instance I would like to replace "Priority: 1" with "Priority: 2"

SQL so far...

```
UPDATE
  response
SET
  notes = REPLACE(
    notes,
    CONCAT('Priority: ', REGEXP '\d'),
    'Priority: 3'
  )
WHERE actionid = '2198602'
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql RexEx would be something like `Priority: [0-9]+`

Comment: Only have mysql 5 - dont have regexp_replace

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned in a comment above that you are using MySQL 5.x, so the REGEXP_REPLACE() function is not available.

This means you have a few options:

### Replace fixed strings, one at a time.

```
UPDATE
  response
SET
  notes = REPLACE(
    notes,
    'Priority: 1',
    'Priority: 3'
  )
WHERE actionid = '2198602';
```

Then do a similar update for 'Priority: 2' and another update for any other value you need to change.

### Replace fixed strings, in a nested fashion.

The result of one REPLACE() is a string, which you can use as the first argument to another REPLACE(). The string will be checked for each input pattern, and the replacement made.

```
UPDATE
  response
SET
  notes = REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
      notes,
      'Priority: 1',
      'Priority: 3'
    ),
    'Priority: 2',
    'Priority: 3'
  )
WHERE actionid = '2198602';
```

### Fetch the value into a client application

Select the value, fetch it, then you can use regular expressions to make string substitutions. Virtually every language has support for regular expressions in some manner.

### Upgrade to MySQL 8.0

Obvious option. Then you can use REGEXP_REPLACE().

Note that MySQL 5.7 will reach end-of-life in October 2023, less than one year away as we write this. You should already be thinking about upgrading to 8.0.